# Messages delimiter, faster in one tag

Tags: html, css, web

I have message delimiter but I think it possible to do it faster:

```
<div style="border-top: 1px solid black; width: 33%; float: left;margin-top: 30px;"></div>
<div style="float: left; margin-top: 25px; width: 33%; text-align: center;">Dzisiaj</div>
<div style="border-top: 1px solid black; margin-top: 30px;width: 33%; float: right;"></div>
<br />
```

The result is good:

```
---------- Dzisiaj -----------
```

But I want to do it like this:

```
<span class="delimiter">Dzisiaj</span>
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a fixed-width border, but I don't think it works with percentage widths:

```
<div style="border-left: 100px solid black; border-right: 100px solid black; text-align: center; line-height: 1px; margin: 0.5em 0;">Dzisiaj</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work properly. It doesn't work with percents and displays "Dzisiaj: at the right side (not center).

Comment: @MichałK. I don't know why you are seeing the text at the right but I already knew it probably didn't work with percents.